# NodeJS HTTP Server - disable HTTP methods, TRACK TRACE etc

Tags: node.js, http

Running `nmap` on my NodeJS HTTP server I get:

```
nmap -p 443 --script http-methods localhost

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-10-28 11:26 BST
Nmap scan report for localhost
Host is up (0.00051s latency).
PORT    STATE SERVICE
443/tcp open  https
| http-methods: ACL BIND CHECKOUT CONNECT COPY DELETE GET HEAD LINK LOCK M-SEARC                                                 H MERGE MKACTIVITY MKCALENDAR MKCOL MOVE NOTIFY PATCH POST PROPFIND PROPPATCH PU                                                 RGE PUT REBIND REPORT SEARCH SUBSCRIBE TRACE UNBIND UNLINK UNLOCK UNSUBSCRIBE
| Potentially risky methods: ACL BIND CHECKOUT CONNECT COPY DELETE LINK LOCK M-S                                                 EARCH MERGE MKACTIVITY MKCALENDAR MKCOL MOVE NOTIFY PATCH PROPFIND PROPPATCH PUR                                                 GE PUT REBIND REPORT SEARCH SUBSCRIBE TRACE UNBIND UNLINK UNLOCK UNSUBSCRIBE
|_See http://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/http-methods.html
MAC Address: AB:CD:75:EF:A5:6D (Unknown)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.12 seconds
```

So I'm looking to disable some of these methods, mainly in the "Potentially risky methods:" list.

This is pretty trivial in Apache, but I can't see any way of doing it in NodeJS.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10381084/custom-http-method-with-nodejs-http-server) talks about editing the C source of Node, but I don't really want to have to do that.

[The node docs](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_methods) show a http.METHODS method, but thats just a get.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Asked on the NodeJS help github and got this response from *bnoordhuis*:

```
const allowedMethods = ['GET','HEAD','POST'];

function onrequest(req, res) {
  if (!allowedMethods.includes(req.method))
    return res.end(405, 'Method Not Allowed');
  // ...
}
```

https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/357

Comment: Can you guide me how did you use, I was using the express wanted to allow only GET, POST

Comment: This method would sit in your front controller. eg from here: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html You would add it to line 3.

Comment: Thanks for the update Kiksy, I did the same way, previously I was placed in the wrong place after reading the GitHub issue it clear my point.