# disable http method in express js

Tags: node.js, http, http-method

im doing nessus testing on my express app
and here what i get

> Based on tests of each method :

- HTTP methods ACL CHECKOUT COPY DELETE GET HEAD LOCK MERGE 
  MKACTIVITY MKCOL MOVE NOTIFY OPTIONS PATCH POST PROPFIND 
  PROPPATCH PUT REPORT SEARCH SUBSCRIBE TRACE UNLOCK UNSUBSCRIBE 
  are allowed on :

  /
  /login
  /styles

i done some search and actually end up here.
 [disable HTTP methods, TRACK TRACE etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40303607/nodejs-http-server-disable-http-methods-track-trace-etc)

the solution

```
const allowedMethods = ['GET','HEAD','POST'];

function onrequest(req, res) {
  if (!allowedMethods.includes(req.method))
    return res.end(405, 'Method Not Allowed');
  // ...
}
```

however i do not understand how to use the solution,
@kiksy comment that: `This method would sit in your front controller. eg from here: expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html You would add it to line 3`

but line 3 was `"const port = 3000"`
it makes me confused

could someone help me on that

FYI, i could not comment becoz i dont have 50 rep

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The comment is essentially saying that you can add this to any of your routes and you're checking the incoming method from each request to see if it is one of the whitelisted HTTP methods, and if not, you're going to return a `405` to let the user know that the method they've tried to hit is unsupported.

You could use a middleware to blanket this for all requests.

```
const allowedMethods = ['GET', 'HEAD', 'POST']

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (!allowedMethods.includes(req.method)) return res.end(405, 'Method Not Allowed')
    return next()
})
```

Comment: Thanks alot. . it works!.

however weird enough...

it still have one left...


' - HTTP methods ACL CHECKOUT COPY DELETE GET HEAD LOCK MERGE 
    MKACTIVITY MKCOL MOVE NOTIFY OPTIONS PATCH POST PROPFIND 
    PROPPATCH PUT REPORT SEARCH SUBSCRIBE TRACE UNLOCK UNSUBSCRIBE 
    are allowed on : 

    /
'

Comment: this does not block OPTIONS method.