# API is responding with status 200 when used with HEAD and OPTIONS method

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, rest, http-method

I created an API with method GET using express which is working fine.

following is the API

```
app.get('/healthcheck', (_req, res) => {
  res.status(200).send({
    state: 'Healthy',
    timestamp: new Date(),
    uptime: process.uptime()
  });
});
```

I am also getting success response with status = 200 when method is replaced with HEAD or OPTIONS. Shown below.

```
curl --location --head 'http://localhost:2003/healthcheck'
```

Although with POST, PUT, PATCH etc methods I am getting status=404.

Since the created API is of type GET, I want to send 404 for all other methods like HEAD, OPTIONS, POST, PATCH etc

only follow request should give status=200

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:2003/healthcheck'
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: This seems like a very weird request. Can you explain why you want this? Getting a status of 200 for GET but not HEAD doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: because it comes under OWASP vulnerabilities: API7:2019 Security Misconfiguration

Comment: You can react to HEAD requests in express: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63649387/get-vs-head-methods-in-express-example Just use .head() or .options() apparently. Note however that I just tested this and replying with 404 in a HEAD request also prevents GET requests. Which is why I found this weird. Can you link to the explainer that says to react with 404 to HEAD requests for valid GET URLs?

Comment: You can write a middleware to block the requests with the unwanted method types and inject that in the routes.
The answer of the below question has such kind of the middleware function.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61226302/disable-http-method-in-express-js

Comment: HEAD method is same as GET without response body & OPTIONS is used by browsers to check allowed methods like CORS and etc, so you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: Pretty sure you're misinterpreting whichever part of API7:2019 you're referring to.

Answer (score 1):

What you request goes straight against the specification of `HEAD` and `POST` methods:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-head

> **The HEAD method is identical to GET** except that the server MUST NOT send content in the response. HEAD is used to obtain metadata about the selected representation without transferring its representation data, often for the sake of testing hypertext links or finding recent modifications.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-options

> This method **allows a client to determine the options and/or requirements associated with a resource**, or the capabilities of a server, without implying a resource action.

By returning `200` for `GET` but `404` for `HEAD` or `OPTIONS`, you are breaking the semantics of the HTTP specification and your server will be hated by clients. **Breaking the specifications rules** is the **vulnerability nr. 1**.

The answer to your question is very simple: **DO NOT DO IT!** :)